# Options, Futures and other derivatives, book by Hull, confusion of currencies

Tags: currency, financial-economics, asset-pricing, currency-exchange

I have a small technical problem with a book by [Hull](http://62.182.86.140/main/3158000/5abdc0446a52c3491bff6b2f8d100ec9/John%20Hull%20-%20Options%2C%20Futures%2C%20and%20Other%20Derivatives-Pearson%20%282021%29.pdf):

on the page 7, the first line, in the 11th edition of his book
Options, Futures and Other Derivatives (please see the snippet below) he writes

"bank is prepared to buy GBP (also known as sterling) in the spot market (i.e., for"

and below he writes

"and sell sterling in the spot market at $1.2220 per GBP".

From the second statement I derive that sterling is not the same as GBP while from the first one I derive that it is.
He writes there "(also known as sterling)".

What's going on here ?

[image]

Comment: Both statements say GBP is sterling also this seems to be English language question not economics one, what do you do not understand from economic perspective? Both sentences talk about GBP (sterling) that’s why second sentence says they are selling sterling at \$1.1222 per GBP (ie per sterling)

Comment: This is about semantics, not economics.

Comment: @1muflon1 Right, I'm quite a beginner in both, economics and English .